# DraggableComponents in vertical view (Java Swing)

Tags: java, swing

This is my first question on this platform so bear with here:

I'm using Java Swing to make a LayerPanel just like in Photoshop, where each child of the LayerPanel is also a Panel that represents a layer. Just like in Photoshop I'm using the mouse to move these children of the LayerPanel using the DraggableComponent class inspired by: enter image description heregable-component>.

The problem lies in re-arranging the layers in the UI. I'm unable to get the swapping of panels to work within the UI.

This is my code thus far:

The DraggableComponent:

```
class DraggableComponent extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    private LayerPanel panel;

    private volatile int screenY = 0;
    private volatile int myY = 0;

    private String name;

    public DraggableComponent(LayerPanel panel, String name) {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 80));
        this.name = name;
        this.panel = panel;
        updateBorder(name);
        setVisible(true);

        setLayout(null);

        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    private void updateBorder(String name) {
        setBorder(new TitledBorder(new DropShadowBorder(), name, TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.BELOW_TOP, null, null));
    }

    private void handleLocation(int y) {
        if (y >= getParent().getHeight() - this.getHeight()) {
            setLocation(getLocation().x, getParent().getHeight() - this.getHeight());
        } else setLocation(getLocation().x, Math.max(y, 0));
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        screenY = e.getYOnScreen();
        myY = getY();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        panel.handleReleased(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        int deltaY = e.getYOnScreen() - screenY;

        handleLocation(myY + deltaY);
        panel.handleLocation(this);
    }

    public void rename(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        updateBorder(name);
    }
}
```

The LayerPanel class:

```
public class LayerPanel extends JPanel {

    private ArrayList<DraggableComponent> components = new ArrayList<>();
    protected int HEIGHT_PER_COMPONENT;

    public LayerPanel(int height, int amountOfComponents) {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, height));
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            components.add(new DraggableComponent(this, Integer.toString(i)));
        }

        updateComponents();
    }

    public void addComponent(String name) {
        components.add(new DraggableComponent(this, name));
        updateComponents();
    }

    private void updateComponents() {
        HEIGHT_PER_COMPONENT = getHeight() / (components.size() + 1);
        removeAll();

        for (DraggableComponent c : components) {
            //c.rename(Integer.toString(components.indexOf(c)));
            add(c);
            c.setLocation(0, HEIGHT_PER_COMPONENT * components.indexOf(c));
        }
    }

    public void handleReleased(DraggableComponent component) {
        updateComponents();
    }

    public void handleLocation(DraggableComponent component) {
        final int index = components.indexOf(component);

        for (DraggableComponent nextComponent : components) {
            final int indexNext = components.indexOf(nextComponent);
            if (component.getY() >= nextComponent.getY() - HEIGHT_PER_COMPONENT / 2 && !component.equals(nextComponent)) {
                Collections.swap(components, indexNext, indexNext - 1);
                updateComponents();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Layers test");

        LayerPanel panel = new LayerPanel(800, 10);

        f.add(panel);
        f.setSize(300, 800);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem lies in re-arranging the layers.

There is no need to manage this yourself.

This is controlled by the `ZOrder` of the components in the panel.

In your `mousePressed` event you can set the `ZOrder` of the component to 0, to make sure this component is painted last, which means it will now paint of top of all the other components on the panel.

Something like:

```
Container container = e.getComponent().getParent();
container.setComponentZOrder(e.getComponent(), 0);
```

Comment: This actually helps with my second problem I was going to have, but my problem lies with UI instead of actually drawing. I meant re-arranging the UI element with the mouse s.t. they are still in line with the layout. After fixing that I'd have to implement this. Thanks for responding @camickr (Edit: I will specifiy better in the question portion of this page)